# Redefine word movement stop characters for editing Clojure code in Vim/GVim

Tags: vim, clojure, clojurescript, macvim

When editing Clojure code in Vim/GVim, I frequently use the `w` word-motion command (and its cousin `b` for backwards word-motion). However, in the default Clojure configuration Vim/GVim ignores common word separator chars such as hyphen, slash, and period.  The following Clojure symbol shows all three:

```clj
clojure.core/select-keys
```

In this case, we want the `w` and `b` word-motion commands to stop at any of the non-alphabetic characters.

How can I modify the default Vim configuration to recognize these word boundaries in Clojure?

Answer (score 6):

The answer is to use the Vim feature `autocmd` to modify the `iskeyword` setting for Clojure files.  Specifically, add these lines to your `~/.vimrc` file:

```
" Remove the period `.`, hyphen, `-`, and slash `/` as keyword chars so "word" movement will stop 
" on these chars (i.e. in a namespace like `proj.some.long.ns.name` or a symbol like `my-clojure-sym`)
" Must do one at a time for 'string lists'
autocmd BufWinEnter,BufNewFile,BufRead *.clj* set iskeyword-=.
autocmd BufWinEnter,BufNewFile,BufRead *.clj* set iskeyword-=-
autocmd BufWinEnter,BufNewFile,BufRead *.clj* set iskeyword-=/
```

When loading a file with the suffix `.clj*`, we remove the three characters period, hypthen, and slash from the `iskeyword` string list, so they are no longer recognized as part of a "keyword". That is, they become word-separator characters. Then, the `w` and `b` word-motion commands will stop there, as we were seeking.

Answer (score 2):

I add an answer for **ideavim** users since, this is the first google result.

Add this line to your .ideavimrc file:

`set iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255,?,-,*,!,+,/,=,<,>,.,:,$`

Comment: thank you, man, you saved me a year